# Aggregate data in RESTful API

Tags: rest

Have an interesting HTTP API question that I'd like some opinions on.  My API allows people to rate things on a 1-10 scale.  I have a `GET /ratings` endpoint that lists a user's ratings.  We also want a way to show the user's average rating per day.  So my question - should the summary be the same url, like `/ratings?data=summary`, or should it be its own url like `/ratingsummaries` or `/ratings/summary`?

As is often the case, I don't think there is a right answer.  Is the summary just another view of ratings, in which case it would be the ratings resource and should be part of `/ratings`?  Or, is a summary of ratings its own resource, in which case it deserves its own url like `/ratingsummaries`?  `/ratings/summary` looks nice too but it isn't really a sub-resource of ratings.

Looking forward to your feedback.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 8):

My opinion is to have it like 
`/ratings/` when ever your are getting back a list of ratings. The search parameters are usually given as `@QueryParam`. Eg `ratings?offset=20&records=50&startDate=xx&endDate=yy`

`/ratings/{id}/` for one particular rating identified by the id.

`/ratings/{id}/votes` for getting for votes on the rating.

Rating summary is different entity from rating so it is a candidate for separte url
`/ratingsummary?startDate=x&endDate=y`

or your path can start with `/ratingsummary`; it can be like
`/ratingsummary/ratings?offset=20&records=50&startDate=xx&endDate=yy`
In this case you have the rating summary, then you can drill down to the list of ratings that contributed to the summary, then to one particilar rating, etc..

It is ideal to follow a pattern like `/entities/{idOfOneEntiity}/{attributeOfEntitiy}` etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  /ratings is a paginated list of each rating, with query params for filtering.  In my situation, the summaries can be any arbitrary date range, which UIs use to show day, week, and month views.  There's 'to' and 'from' parameters for that.  And we want to get more granular in the future, like hourly reports, or showing nighttime ratings per day over some date range.  Knowing that, how would you handle it?

Comment: I had a different understanding of the summary. The answer is updated.